# Experience Analytics Report display off by 1 day

Tags: experience-analytics, reporting

I am seeing a different report based on the computer that I am logged in to for the Sitecore Anayltics Reports.  I am running on Sitecore v9.0.2, we have one Server which is running the CM, Processing, Reporting, and xConnect roles.  And then 2 Content Delivery Servers. All of these are located in US Central Time Zone.

When I RDP into the Content Management Server, which is Central Time, and view the Analytics, I am seeing the correct report output, for days Feb 1st to Feb 5th
[image: CMS Report View]

However, when I view the analytics from my local machine, which is Pacific Time, I see the exact same graph, but the date labels are wrong by 1 day, even though the Response that I get from the server has the correct dates in the JSON object.

[image: Local report view]

If I change my local computer's time zone to Central Time, to match the server, then the Reports are displaying correctly.  However this is not a valid solution, and I can't have people changing their computer's timezone just to view reports.

I have tried changing the "ServerDateTime" Configuration value to "Pacific Standard Time"  However, I did not see any immediate changes, but I was wondering if making that change will only affect future interactions with the site, or if that should update the graphs immediately.

Has anyone experienced anything like this before?

Comment: Have you checked the <setting name="ServerTimeZone" value=""/> value in your Sitecore config? If this blank, it takes the operating system time zone. Since you are in two different timezones, wondering if this could be the issue.